# How to call controller method from service in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I wonder if I can call controller method from service.

I know that Service is singleton and I can't inject `$scope` to the service.

In my case I manage Google Maps in service and want to open modal Dialog when user right clicks on Polygon.

As I know, to open/create new instance of dialog, somehow Service must notify controller to do that.

This is a template with controller + method and service: [Template](http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/1105/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);        

function MyCtrl($scope,  gridService, $timeout) {    
    // how to call "foo" method from service?
    $scope.foo = function(){
       alert('called from service');
    };     
}

myApp.service('gridService', ['$timeout', function ( $timeout) {       
        var grid = {
                    fetching: false,
                    pristine: true,
                    pageType: 'Edit'
                }       

       return {
            gridSetup: function () {               
               return grid;
            },
           setGridSetup: function (newGrid) {
              }
        } 
}]);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do not need to call controller from the service - in general the single service could be used by any controller so service shall know nothing about them. In most cases controller calls to the service in react to some user's action and then you need to update view from controller somehow when service did its work (get response from server, etc.). I see following general ways how to do it.

**1. Use callbacks.**

```
//controller
$scope.onButtonClick = function() {
    $scope.label = "wait, loading...";
    function onSuccess(result) {
        $scope.label = "done! result is " + result;
    }
    myService.doSomeWork(param1, param2, onSuccess);
}


//service
doSomeWork: function(param1, param2, onSuccess) {
    $.get({...}, onSuccess);
}
```

So you provide a callback for each action.

**2. Subscribe on events** 
You may use jQuery for events subscribing/triggering

```
//controller
$(myService).on('update', function() {
    $scope.lastUpdateTime = new Date();
});
$scope.onButtonClick = function() {
     myService.doUpdate();
}


//service
doUpdate: function() {
    $.get({...}, function onOk() {
        $(this).trigger('update');
    });
}
```

**3. Use promises**
A lot of built-in angular services return promise objects, you may use them too:

```
//controller
myService.doSomething(param1).then(function(result) {
    $scope.result = result;
});


//service
doSomething: function(param1) {
    return $http.get({...});
}
```

**4. Share some data**
An example is `$resource` service - for example when you call `query` method it returns empty array-like object that could be safely put to scope and then fills it with values when http request is done.

```
//controller
$scope.options = myService.options;
$scope.onClick = function() { myService.update() }


//service
options: [],
update: function() {
    var self = this;
    $http.get({...}).success(function(res) {
        self.options.splice(0, self.options.length); //to keep same array
        self.options.push.apply(self.options, res.data.options); 
    });
}
```

In all these cases services and controllers are separated, services could be used with any controller and you may easily write unit-tests on services that will not break if you change your controller/view part somehow.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: you don't.

The service exists to manipulate data, nothing else. And it really shouldn't care "why" it's doing what it's doing. You ask the service to do something and wait for a response.

Personally I prefer using promises to resolve async operations (i.e. to notify the controller about a state change) since it's heavily supported by many angular services like $http. 
But feel free to use callbacks of you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use directive instead service. With directive I can use callbacks. For service I can use $rootScope broadcast but goole maps with directive will be right way I think.

Comment: You are right, I completely forgot about promises. Updated my answer to have it more complete, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to have a dialog service which you can inject into the grid service. So when the user right clicks on the polygon the handler would call open on the dialog service.

Take a look at the [modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) service on angular ui as an example.