# How can empty service function notify controller function without scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have service where periodically calling function foo(). It is empty function.
How I can notify controller that this function was called without using scope?

I found solutions like this (for example **1. Use callbacks.**): https://stackoverflow.com/a/21391842/6613516

But there is scope and I finally don't understand what does mean "get({...}, on Success" there,  and what is {...}. How can I use it?

Comment: `$.get({...}, onSuccess);`...the first part `$.get({...}, ` calls to your service endpoint, and the `onSuccess` part calls the `onSuccess` function and do something with the result.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. My function in service is calling when button clicked, so for a what i need get() in this function? if i only need to notify controller?

Comment: Please read the following article https://www.sitepoint.com/callbacks-javascript/

Comment: thx for the article